# While loop with user input- cannot get the while loop to stop asking for user input

Tags: java

I am trying to make the while loop stop asking for user input once the user enters "stop", but i cannot get it to stop asking the user for input.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    exampletoday llist=new exampletoday();
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the first operator or operand: ");
    String first=keyboard.nextLine();
    llist.addNode(first);
    while(true)
    {
    System.out.println("Enter the next operand or operator or stop to stop: ");
    String next=keyboard.nextLine();
    llist.addNode(next);
    if(next=="stop")
    break;
}
```

Comment: ``if ("stop".equals(next)) break;``

Answer (score -1):

Use `.equals()` to compare Strings.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    exampletoday llist=new exampletoday();
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the first operator or operand: ");
    String first=keyboard.nextLine();
    llist.addNode(first);
    while(true)
    {
    System.out.println("Enter the next operand or operator or stop to stop: ");
    String next=keyboard.nextLine();
    llist.addNode(next);
    if(next.equals("stop"))
    break;
}
```